# Writing custom matchers in rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, matcher

I have just made the switch from java dev to Ruby/Python. I have been tasked with writing custom matchers in rspec. I am used to using tools like hamcrest and Shazamcrest (which was awesome) in java. Are their any such tools in rspec that will make my life easier ?

Answer (score 0):

Example of custom matcher:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual % expected == 0
  end
end

RSpec.describe 9 do
  it { is_expected.to be_a_multiple_of(3) }
end

RSpec.describe 9 do
  it { is_expected.not_to be_a_multiple_of(4) }
end

# fail intentionally to generate expected output
RSpec.describe 9 do
  it { is_expected.to be_a_multiple_of(4) }
end

# fail intentionally to generate expected output
RSpec.describe 9 do
  it { is_expected.not_to be_a_multiple_of(3) }
end
```

Check documentation for writing custom matchers for RSpec [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher)!

Good luck!